# Why is a scrollbar added to the browser window when body's width is 100%?

Tags: html, css

If I give the `html` element `width: 100%` no scroll-bar is added. But if I give `body` element `width: 100%` then a scroll bar is added. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


    * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {      
      width: 100%;
     }
    .bodycontainer3 {
      width: 100%;
      border: 50px solid gray;
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="bodycontainer3">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is Why is a scrollbar added to the browser window when body's width is 100%?

Comment: Have you removed the default padding/margin from the `body`?

Comment: `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% }`

Answer (score 3):

The `html` and `body` elements are already 100% wide by default so setting them to something else is unnecessary.

However, the `body` has default padding which should be removed as part of a CSS reset.

For that matter, `div` are block level and are also 100% wide by default.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  /* width: 100%; not required */
}
body {
  /* width:100% not required */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bodycontainer3 {
  /* width:100% not required */
  border: 50px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="bodycontainer3">
    hello
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: width 100% to html is required. Otherwise the divs inside body won't inherit width. E.g. `width: 50%` on a div won't work.

Comment: Perhaps width: 50% is still working. I read somewhere that for divs to inherit width/height the html or body must be given 100% width/height.

Comment: To inherit a height yes..but that wasn't your question.

Comment: For the current question. I now got that body has default margin -- which was the issue. I knew about default padding that's why I added `box-sizing: border-box`.